# Define query type for "SearchAction"

Tags: search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I'm struggling to find a solution. I'm looking for the way to define a search keyword. For a website you can lookup a vehicles information by vin number. Same thought process as would be for looking up a phone number

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to let Google ([Sitelinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)) know that "search_term_string" is a vin number. Even just requiring to have exactly 17 chars would be nice.

Any ideas? Does this schema even support it? Does it support phone numbers?